# Can I not access a protected super class instance variable with super class reference?

Tags: java, inheritance

Unable to access protected instance variable with superclass reference whereas able to access a protected function of the same super class with the super class reference

```
package Test;
import Different.Exam;

public class Test  {
    protected int a = 4;

    protected int add(int a, int b){
       return  a+b;
    }
}
```

Sub class

```
package Different;

import Test.Test;

public class Exam extends Test {
   protected void methodWithDefaultAccess(){
       Exam exam = new Exam();
       exam.add(1, 2);
       System.out.println("A in super class is.. "+a);
       System.out.println("A in super class is .." exam.a);
   }
}
```

In this case I am able to access the protected function with super class reference but unable to access the instance variable with super class reference.

Comment: Test t = new Exam(); provide getters and setters in Test class

Comment: What language is this?  Java?  C#?  You need to tag your question with the programming language in use.

Comment: Test t = new Exam(); does not work without a getter. I do understand the significance of getters and setters but I'm trying to know why is there a difference in how a function and instance variable is being accessed.

Comment: What's the question exactly? If the question is "why doesn't this compile?", then it's because you forgot a `+` between `"A in super class is .."` and `exam.a`. It has nothing to do with protected members.

Comment: I guess **exam.a** will work fine

Answer (score 0):

If the question is why declaring the reference as `Test exam = new Exam();` makes `exam.a` inaccessible, then the Java Language Specification (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.2) states that:

> A protected member or constructor of an object may be accessed from outside the package in which it is declared only by code that is responsible for the implementation of that object(...). Let C be the class in which a protected member is declared. Access is permitted only within the body of a subclass S of C. In addition, (...) If the access is by a field access expression E.Id, where E is a Primary expression, or by a method invocation expression E.Id(. . .), where E is a Primary expression, then the access is permitted if and only if the type of E is S or a subclass of S.

In plain English: from within a child class, you cannot access protected members declared in the parent class using a reference **whose type is the parent class**. The type of the reference must be the **child class** (or its descendant class).